# How I avoid the "NULL" in the first "Field Name" of Hive table

Tags: hadoop, hive, bigdata

First of all I have created the table "emp" in Hive by using below commands:

```
create table emp (id INT, name STRING, address STRING)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t';
```

Then load the data in this "emp" table by this below command:
LOAD DATA LOCAL INPATH '\home\cloudera\Desktop\emp.txt' overwrite into table emp;

When I select the data from "emp" table: it show me first field of table Null
like this:

[image]

Comment: Can you share the emp.txt file?

Comment: its a tab Delimited file. 
"id" "Name" "Address"
these are the fields.
it show "ID" Fields NULL

Comment: Are you adding "" to data in ur file ?

Comment: No, I was not using "" in my file.
Just put the "Column" name and the data for those "column"

Comment: P.s. please replace the picture with text (format it with ctrl+k)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have an header row in your file and the first value `id` cannot be converted into `INT` therefore being replaced by `NULL`.

add `tblproperties ("skip.header.line.count"="1")` to your table definition

For an existing table -

`alter table emp set tblproperties ("skip.header.line.count"="1");`

Comment: Should i need to create the table "emp" again for this command
or any other way to add it ??

Comment: alter table empset tblproperties ("skip.header.line.count"="1"); 
I have been using above command it gives me an error : 
"Cannot recognize input near 'tblproperties' "

Comment: typo. check again

Comment: when i write this command 
select * from emp;
it did not show column name ?

Comment: `set hive.cli.print.header=true`

Comment: Thanks :) Working

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142733/discussion-between-mudi-and-dudu-markovitz).